# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '.obj'

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fatal-error

I have a big problem with building a simple program. I am using many tutorials, instructions and I can't solve it. I edit the variable's path as follows:

> C/C++->General->Additionals Include
>   Directories->MyOpenCv\build\include  Linker->General->Additionals
>   Library Directories->MyOpenCv\build\x86\vc11\lib
>   Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies->*I added .libs

The same in Debug and Release.
Windows 8 x64, VS2012 x32, OpenCV 2.4.5

Comment: Are you using a Custom Build Step by any chance? Better yet, can you publish your .vcxproj

Answer (score 0):

Go to C/C++ -> Output Files and check Object File Name. Chances are it contains a bogus macro reference.

Comment: can you elaborate? where is this menu? why would this solve the problem?

Comment: @andrewrk right click your project in solution explorer. then properties. and there will be c/c++

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++, I have found for Visual Studio the location listed below is ***NOT*** the correct way to reference library files during linking the compiler-linking stage (at least in Community Version 2017). I had a project folder called '**lib**' which contained all my .lib files. Originally I had specified a value like

```
Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories: $(ProjectDir)lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

I was getting error messages like:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'lib.obj'
```

I figured out ***this*** was the correct way to specify the library directories:

```
VC++ Directories --> Library Directories
```

In my case, my value was:

```
VC++ Directories --> Library Directories: $(ProjectDir)lib;$(LibraryPath)
```